# The dots at the corner of an image not showing up

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I add an new image, the blue dots at the 4 corner of the image that allow you to adjust the size are not showing. So do text and other elements.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

You can press 'T' or click this red rectangle on this image.
I hope it will work for you.